# How can I access a temporary column which has been created with a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have created a column with the alias Previousodds. I want to access this column and use it to subset the returned table. My query is:

```
WITH t as
 (SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
   odds,
   col4
FROM 
 stuff)

SELECT * 
  , LAG(odds,1,0) OVER (partition by [col1] ORDER BY [col2] AS Previousodds
FROM t

-- What I would like to do but can't:
WHERE (1/Odds - 1/Previousodds) > 0.04
```

Comment: Wrap the query with another select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick that SELECT statement in a subquery:

```
WITH t as
 (SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
   odds,
   col4
FROM 
 stuff)

SELECT * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT * 
           , LAG(odds,1,0) OVER (partition by [col1] ORDER BY [col2] AS Previousodds
         FROM t
    )subquery
WHERE (1/Odds - 1/Previousodds) > 0.04
```

Subqueries and CTEs are the same beast too, so you could move that CTE as a subquery of this subquery, or you could move this SELECT that is now a subquery into the CTE.

Comment: From the original table.. it's in the select fields

Comment: Oh yes! I see it in there. I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @JohnF . . . Eid's answer is not only simpler but it avoids a (potential?) divide-by-zero error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH t as
 (SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
   odds,
   col4,
     LAG(odds) OVER (partition by [col1] ORDER BY [col2] AS Previousodds

 FROM  stuff
)

SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE (1/Odds - 1/Previousodds) > 0.04
```

Comment: I would change `lag(odds, 1, 0)` to `lag(odds)` to avoid a divide-by-zero error.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this. Create another CTE using the first one to materialise and use them in your actual query. JNevill's answer will work too.

```
WITH t as
 (SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
   odds,
   col4
FROM 
 stuff)
, 
x as (
SELECT * 
  , LAG(odds,1,0) OVER (partition by [col1] ORDER BY [col2] AS Previousodds
FROM t)    
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE (1/Odds - 1/Previousodds) > 0.04
```